# Transformar level em Variável

Tags: r, classes

Gostaria de criar uma nova coluna, transformando `Tab1612SojaRend$Nível.Territorial` os levels "Grande Região" e "Unidade da Federação" em colunas. A "Unidade da Federação tem que estar na mesma coluna das cidades de acordo com o Estado. Outro ponto que precisava seria eliminar o estado da variável "Município, Grande Região e Unidade da Federação".

```
library(sidrar)
Tab1612SojaRend <-get_sidra(1612,variable = 112, period = c("last" = 22),
                        geo = c("Region","State","City"),
                        geo.filter = list("Region" = 3,"Region" = 3,"Region" = 3),
                        classific = 'c81',
                        category = list(2713))

Tab1612SojaRend$Nível.Territorial <- 
as.factor(Tab1612SojaRend$Nível.Territorial)

dput(Tab1612SojaRendsudeste[c(1:10, 101:110, 24001:24010), ])
structure(list(`Nível Territorial (Código)` = c("6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6"), `Nível Territorial` = c("Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", "Município", 
"Município", "Município"), `Município, Grande Região e Unidade da Federação 
(Código)` = c("3100104", 
"3100104", "3100104", "3100104", "3100104", "3100104", "3100104", 
"3100104", "3100104", "3100104", "3100500", "3100500", "3100500", 
"3100500", "3100500", "3100500", "3100500", "3100500", "3100500", 
"3100500", "3506300", "3506300", "3506359", "3506359", "3506359", 
"3506359", "3506359", "3506359", "3506359", "3506359"), `Município, Grande 
 Região e Unidade da Federação` = c("Abadia dos Dourados - MG", 
"Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados 
 - MG", 
"Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados 
 - MG", 
"Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados - MG", "Abadia dos Dourados 
 - MG", 
"Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", 
"Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", 
"Açucena - MG", "Açucena - MG", "Bernardino de Campos - SP", 
"Bernardino de Campos - SP", "Bertioga - SP", "Bertioga - SP", 
"Bertioga - SP", "Bertioga - SP", "Bertioga - SP", "Bertioga - SP", 
"Bertioga - SP", "Bertioga - SP"), `Ano (Código)` = c("1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2016", "2017", "1996", "1997", "1998", 
"1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"), Ano = c("1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2016", "2017", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"), `Variável (Código)` = c("112", 
"112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", 
"112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", 
"112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", 
"112", "112"), Variável = c("Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento 
 médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção", 
"Rendimento médio da produção", "Rendimento médio da produção"
 ), `Produto das lavouras temporárias (Código)` = c("2713", "2713", 
"2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", 
"2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", 
"2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713", 
"2713", "2713", "2713", "2713"), `Produto das lavouras temporárias` = 
c("Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em grão)", 
"Soja (em grão)"), `Unidade de Medida (Código)` = c("33", "33", 
"33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", 
"33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", 
"33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33"), `Unidade de Medida` = c("Quilogramas 
 por 
 Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por 
Hectare", 
"Quilogramas por Hectare", "Quilogramas por Hectare"), Valor = c(1620, 
2202, 2200, 2400, 2800, 2880, 2700, 2800, 2429, 2700, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2550, 2550, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
24002L, 24003L, 24004L, 24005L, 24006L, 24007L, 24008L, 24009L, 
24010L, 24011L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Parece que a API está instável. @Everton, poderia compartilhar o resultado de `dput(Tab1612SojaRend[c(1:10, 101:110, 24001:24010), ])`?

Comment: Bom dia @TomásBarcellos. Não estou conseguindo colar, está dando comprimento excedido.

Comment: Menos linhas então. Talvez `dput(Tab1612SojaRend[c(1:5, 101:105, 24001:24005), ])`. A ideia é ter algumas linhas de cada grupo. Se conseguir de outra maneira também serve

Comment: structure(list(`Nível Territorial (Código)` = c("6"), `Nível Territorial` = c("Município"), `Município, Grande Região e Unidade da Federação (Código)` = c("3100104"), `Município, Grande Região e Unidade da Federação` = c( "Bertioga - SP"), Ano = c("1996"), `Variável (Código)` = c("112"), Variável = c("Rend m da produção"), `Produto das lavouras temporárias (Código)` = c("2713"), `Produto das lavouras temporárias` = c("Soja (em grão)"), `Unidade de Medida (Código)` = c("33"), `Unidade de Medida` = ("Quilogramas por Hectare"), Valor = c( 2429,NA), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar o resultado do `dput` lá. Na pergunta o primeiro vai caber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a API da SIDRA estava instável ou muito lenta, fiz essa pequena alteração no código (removi os municípios da consulta) para ter dados similares para trabalhar.

```
library(sidrar)
Tab1612SojaRend <- get_sidra(1612,variable = 112, period = c("last" = 22),
                             geo = c("Region","State"),
                             geo.filter = list("Region" = 3,"Region" = 3),
                             # geo = "Region", geo.filter = list("Region" = 3),
                             classific = 'c81',
                             category = list(2713))
```

Para fazer o desejado, é possível usar a função `spread()` para espalhar os valores `Nível Territorial` em várias colunas.

```
library(tidyverse)
resp1 <- Tab1612SojaRend %>% 
  spread(`Nível Territorial`, Valor)
```

Agora, sempre cabe perguntar: **é isso mesmo que você deseja fazer?**

Vamos dar uma olhada em `resp1`:

```
glimpse(resp1)
Observations: 110
Variables: 13
$ `Nível Territorial (Código)`                    <chr> "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2",...
$ `Grande Região e Unidade da Federação (Código)` <chr> "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3",...
$ `Grande Região e Unidade da Federação`          <chr> "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sudest...
$ `Ano (Código)`                                  <chr> "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999...
$ Ano                                             <chr> "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999...
$ `Variável (Código)`                             <chr> "112", "112", "112", "112", "...
$ Variável                                        <chr> "Rendimento médio da produção...
$ `Produto das lavouras temporárias (Código)`     <chr> "2713", "2713", "2713", "2713...
$ `Produto das lavouras temporárias`              <chr> "Soja (em grão)", "Soja (em g...
$ `Unidade de Medida (Código)`                    <chr> "33", "33", "33", "33", "33",...
$ `Unidade de Medida`                             <chr> "Quilogramas por Hectare", "Q...
$ `Grande Região`                                 <dbl> 2072, 2330, 2114, 2518, 2316,...
$ `Unidade da Federação`                          <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
```

Veja que as variáveis criadas se intercalam entre `Grande Região` ter valor e `Unidade da Federação` ser `NA` e o contrário.

```
any(!is.na(resp1$`Grande Região`) & !is.na(resp1$`Unidade da Federação`))
# [1] FALSE
```

Ocorre que rompemos o [terceiro princípio das tabelas `tidy`](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html): Cada unidade observacional deve ter sua própria tabela, e aqui estamos misturando Unidades da Federação com Regiões.

Por estes motivos, eu acharia melhor trabalhar da seguinte maneira:

```
resp2 <- split(Tab1612SojaRend, Tab1612SojaRend$`Nível Territorial`)
regioes <- resp2[[1]]
ufs <- resp2[[2]]
```

Outra maneira ainda, seria mudar o chamado da API para retornar uma unidade observacional (regiões/UFs/municípios) de cada vez.